# Apply a Module to All Past Articles

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm using Drupal for the first time and I'm hoping to move my existing website over to it. We've successfully imported our existing articles (in our own, custom format, stored in MySQL, moved over to Drupal's article system) and we're looking to get the site going. I tried installing the Colorbox module (I believe it was [this one](https://drupal.org/project/colorbox)) but it doesn't seem to apply to all previous articles (the ones we imported). I've used WordPress before, and plugins (Colorbox, at least) had the ability to apply themselves  to previous posts. Is this possible in Drupal?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Drupal rar!

[Colorbox](https://drupal.org/project/colorbox) module in Drupal may have different needs (probably attributes on the images) than the similar plugin in Wordpress. Although both are using the same js plugin this does not mean that they work the same way.

From the Drupal Colorbox documentation:

> Load images from custom links in a Colorbox
>
> Add the class "**colorbox**" to the link and point the src to the image
>   you want to display in the Colorbox.

1. Are the images set like this in your website? What is the code now for the images you want to display in a colorbox popup?
2. Did you follow the installation instructions for the Drupal Colorbox module?

Comment: Because I imported the images from my previous database, they don't have the "colorbox" class in them. The reason I thought this would work is because WordPress allows for their plugins to modify all previous posts with the colorbox (or similar) plugins. I'm guessing Drupal won't allow this, though.

Comment: I do not know a lot about WP but Drupal can change the output formatter to Colorbox popup if the images belong to an image field.

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? If so please give some feedback.

Comment: I ended up abandoning Drupal and went with WordPress, as it was much more geared towards what I wanted to do.